# drawImage not working on canvas

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, draw, chart.js

I'm using the library chart.js and I want to draw an image. I set some css to make the canvas "responsive" but the img isn't displayed.

css:

```
canvas{
    width: 100% !important;
    height: auto !important;
}
```

Canvas:

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <div class="content-panel">
    <h4><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i> Categories</h4>
        <div class="panel-body text-center">
            <canvas id="radar_best"></canvas>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
base_image = new Image();
base_image.src = '../../images/no_data_graph.jpg';
console.log(base_image.src);
console.log("setting image");
document.getElementById("radar_best").getContext("2d").drawImage(base_image, 100,100);
```

The img URL is fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You can only draw image on canvas when image is ready, put that drawImage to `base_image.onload`, which is a callback function. As your current code do not ensure the image is loaded when you execute the drawImage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Load an image takes time, when you execute the `drawImage` in your current code, it may not loaded when you want to use it, and that would comes out an unexpected result.

What you should do is use `base_image.onload`, which will be called when image is fully loaded. Then you can use `drawImage` to draw the loaded image on the canvas.

```
base_image = new Image();
base_image.onload = function() {
    // When image loaded, you can then draw it on the canvas.
    document.getElementById("radar_best").getContext("2d").drawImage(base_image, 100,100);
};

base_image.onerror = function() {
    // It's always good to have some error handling.
    console.log('image load error').
    // do somthing else....
};
//always set the src after the onload callback as it is possible that image is already loaded in the browser memory hence onload event will never fire
base_image.src = '../../images/no_data_graph.jpg';
console.log(base_image.src);
console.log("setting image");
```